# Is this proof of the fact that $\rho^* :K[GL(V)] \rightarrow K[G]$ surjective $\implies \rho : G \rightarrow GL(V)$ injective valid?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G \subset K^n$ denote an affine algebraic group, $K$ an algebraically closed field and $(\rho,V)$ a regular representation of $G$ (i.e. $\dim V < \infty$ and $ \rho$ is a group homomorphism which is also a morphism of affine varieties). For any affine variety $X$ we denote by $K[X]$ the coordinate ring of $X$. I'm trying to prove that if
$$ \rho^* : K[GL(V)] \rightarrow K[G] : f \mapsto f \circ \rho$$
is surjective, then it follows that the representation is injective $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(V)$. This is stated as a fact in my lecture notes but with no proof given.

---

**Proof**

Let $g_1,g_2 \in G $ and denote by $g_1,g_2$ the maps $\{ 0\} \rightarrow G : 0 \mapsto g_i.$ Then
$$ \rho(g_1) = \rho (g_2) \iff \rho \circ g_1 = \rho \circ g_2 \implies g_1^* \circ \rho^* = g_2^*\circ \rho^*.$$
Since $\rho^*$ is surjective it follows that $g_1^* \circ \rho^* = g_2^*\circ \rho^* \implies g_1^* = g_2^*.$ That is,

$$ f(g_1) = f(g_2) \quad \forall f \in K[G].$$

View elements in $K[G]$ as the restriction of polynomials $f \in K[x_1,...,x_n]$ to $G \subset K^n$. That is let
$$ G = \{f_{\vert_G} : f \in K[x_1,...,x_n] \}$$
and consider the linear maps (which are polynomials) of the form
$$ \alpha : K^n \rightarrow K : (x_1,...,x_n) \mapsto \sum_i \alpha_i x_i$$
for $(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) \in K^n.$
Then let $g_1 = (X_1,...,X_n)$ and $g_2 = (Y_1,...,X_n)$ and we have

$$ \alpha(g_1) = \alpha(g_2) \implies \sum_i \alpha_i(X_i-Y_i) = 0.$$

Thus $ f(g_1) = f(g_2)$ for all $f \in K[G]$ implies that point $(X_1-Y_1,...,X_n-Y_n)$ belongs to all the hyperplanes in the vector space $K^n$ at the same time. This implies

$$ (X_1-Y_1,...,X_n-Y_n) = 0.$$
That is, $g_1 = g_2.$

Is this correct ?

Comment: I don't understand how you get a map $K[GL(V)]\to K[G]$

Comment: @reuns Which map are you taking about ? $\rho^*$ ?

Comment: @reuns We can view polynomials $f \in K[x_1,...,x_n]$ as functions from $f :K^n \to K$. Since $G \subset K^n$ I denote by $f_{\vert_G}$ the restriction of $f$ to $G$.

Comment: Let $f \in K[GL(V)]$. Then I can view $f$ as a function from $GL(V) \to K.$ Then $\rho^*(f) = f \circ \rho$ can be viewed as a function from $G$ to $K$. My definition of $\rho$ being a morphism of affine varieties is exactly that the image of $\rho^*$ lies entirely in $K[G]$. That is, that $\rho^*$ maps a polynomial $f \in K[GL(V)]$ to a polynomial function $\rho^*(f)$ on $G$.

Comment: Ok I didn't get that you meant the coordinate rings, not the group rings